# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(RegisterPageModule)[AccessProviders -> AccessProviders]

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I have a problem in my **Ionic** app with **AngularJS**, in `register.page.ts`; when i am going to add the `AccessProviders` path in the project the project says:`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(RegisterPageModule)[AccessProviders -> AccessProviders -> AccessProviders -> AccessProviders]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for AccessProviders!`

**I have created the access providers folder and files manually.**

**register.page.ts**

```
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import { ToastController, LoadingController, AlertController } from "@ionic/angular";
import {AccessProviders} from "../../providers/access-providers";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

    name: string = "";
    gender: string = "";
    dob: string = "";
    email: string = "";
    password: string = "";
    confirm_password: string = "";
    disabledButton;

  constructor(
      private router: Router,
      private toastCtrl: ToastController,
      private alertCtrl: AlertController,
      private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
      private accsPrvds: AccessProviders,
  ) { }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
      this.disabledButton = false;
  }
```

**access-providers.ts**

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/timeout';

@Injectable()
export class AccessProviders {
    server: string = 'http://localhost:8100/register'; //should change.

    constructor(
        public http: HttpClient
    ) {

    }

    postData(body, file) {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        });

        let options = {
            headers: headers
        };

        return this.http.post(this.server + file, JSON.stringify(body), options)
            .timeout(59000)// 59 sec timeout
            .map(res => res);
    }
}
```

**How i can solve this problem?** I hope got my answer.

Answer (score 8):

ADD blow code inside your `access-providers.ts` file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; // at top

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' // just before your class
})
export class AccessProviders {}
```

Comment: Thanks, Najam, it solves my problem, but what is the purpose behind it

Comment: Thanks, Najam, it solves my problem, but what is the purpose behind it

Comment: it will inject your provider at root level of your application so you can access it anywhere without importing it into `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that `HttpClientModule` is registered at the level of `AppModule`

Answer (score 2):

Just add this in your app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
/////
@NgModule({
imports: [ HttpClientModule ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add it under providers in your app.modules.ts file.

If you only need the class in one page you could add it to the page.module.ts file of the corresponding page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I found my solution here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20339#issuecomment-354767429

I had to import
"**import {HttpClientModule} from '@ angular / common / http'**;" in
**imports: [HttpClientModule]**, inside the module that references the component.

Answer (score 0):

In your app module

You have to add at the top :

```
import {AccessProviders} from "../../providers/access-providers";
```

On the same file, find providers and just add AccessProviders to the list of providers.